# How exactly can you get the "Liberty Completionist: Hard" achievement?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I was having problems with one particular mission so I played it in normal after getting really frustrated.

If I finish the rest of the missions in hard, and then I come back and replay that mission in hard, will I still get the achievement?

Comment: I would think so as the achievement is tied to defeating the mission on Hard, regardless of campaign progress.

Comment: Yes, you will still get the achievement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from [other questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/how-do-i-earn-sc2s-hurry-up-its-raid-night-achievement) like this, it seems that SC2 keeps track of your progress in each mission separately from your campaign completion, saves, etc.  So as long as you complete all required objectives for the achievement *at some point*, you should get it.