# Is it true that I won't see completed missions time if I restart a campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I restart a campaign I will still have all my achievements. But as far as I understood, I won't see completed missions time if I restart a campaign?

Is this true?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/how-do-i-earn-sc2s-hurry-up-its-raid-night-achievement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's true, in the new campaign you will NOT see old missions.

You CAN see old missions ONLY if you load an OLD game, so load up an old save (auto-save of OLD) and then you can play old missions.

Edit:
If you don't save the new campaign and load the old campaign, the new one will be lost, but there should be an autosave created on creation/first play iirc.

Comment: What happens to the "new" campaign if you load a game from the previous one?

Comment: @Juan Manuel added edit