# Is there a way to track total mission playtime?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty has an achievement to complete the campaign on Normal in under 8 hours. I've already seen this question: [How do I earn SC2's "Hurry up, it's raid night" achievement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4487/28182), which lists how to **earn** the achievement, but is there any way to **track** how much time in total has been spent?

Or do I need to go to the mission screen and add up all the times manually?

I"m just thinking it may be easier to replay a mission for a better time (by reloading a save from before that mission), then it would be to get through the entire campaign to find out I missed by 10 seconds or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and you can't replay mission either, I made this mistake myself.
You could maybe time yourself externally. I just did it as fast as I could and hoped for the best. Luckily that was good enough.