# Wings of Liberty in as few missions as possible

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm trying to beat the WoL campaign in as few missions as possible. Can anyone tell me which order of missions I should go in to do so?

Comment: The answer on this question should help you: [How do I earn SC2's "Hurry up, it's raid night" achievement?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/how-do-i-earn-sc2s-hurry-up-its-raid-night-achievement)